# Find all the rows where column is letter case postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, database, postgresql

I have a table in postgres database where I need to find all the rows -

- Between two dates where `fromTo` is date column.
- And also only those rows where column `data` contains mix of lower and upper case letters. for eg: `eCTiWkAohbQAlmHHAemK`

I can do between two dates as shown below but confuse on second point on how to do that?

```
SELECT * FROM test where fromTo BETWEEN '2022-09-08' AND '2022-09-23';
```

Data type for `fromTo` column is shown below -

```
fromTo          | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Why you use two times `from` in one select ? should not be ? :
`SELECT * FROM test where data BETWEEN '2022-09-08' AND '2022-09-23';`

Comment: @Nickname_used Because they called the column `from`. Dicey.

Comment: Yeah I renamed it now. Date column is `fromTo` and data column has lettercase letters. I need to find all the rows between two dates and also `data`column should have mix of lower and upper case letters.

Comment: @rosed Do `FOO` and `foo` match? How about `FÕÕ`?

Comment: @Schwern If `data` column has all lowercase letter then I don't want that in my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) to check that it is only alphabetical characters and at least one uppercase character.

```
select *
from foo
where data ~ '[[:upper:]]' and data ~ '^[[:alpha:]]+$';
  and fromTo BETWEEN '2022-09-08' AND '2022-09-23'
```

The [character classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) will match all alphabetical characters, including those with accents.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/hYPR4M8n).

Note that this may not be able to make use of an index. If your table is large, you may need to reconsider how you're storing the data.

Comment: If data column has all lowercase letters then I don't want that in my output but if it has uppercase letters or mix of uppercase and lowercase then I want that in my output. Will above query still work?

Comment: @rosed I've edited the answer to match what you need. Please [edit that detail into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73862897/edit), and include some examples.